# submit button not working in hangman game(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When the submit button is clicked I cannot get the desired output I want. It has to display a image and a label to show if he has won or not but that doesn't seem to work
the code is as follows:

```
def submit():
    ans.sort()
    answer.sort()
    if ans == answer:
        root2.destroy()
        root3.destroy()
        root4.destroy()
        label2.destroy()
        label3.destroy()
        load=Image.open('win.png')
        render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img=Label(image=render)
        img.image=render
        img.grid(row=0,column=15)
        label4=Label(text="CONGRATULATIONS YOU WIN",font="Times 18")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=15,pady=20)
```

The button function used for submit is as follows:

```
btn30 = Button(root4, text="SUBMIT",bg="Cyan", fg="Black",width=8,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda:submit)
btn30.grid(column=11, row=18,pady=5)
```

The entire code of the program is:

```
from tkinter import*
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from collections import Counter

def emptyblocks(word):
    global n
    global root2
    root2 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root2.grid(row = 5 , column = 1)
    n=len(word)
    i=0
    global button
    button = []
    for j in range(n):
        btni = Button(root2, text=" ",bg="White", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'))
        btni.grid(column=i+3, row=4, pady=40)
        button.append(btni)
        i=i+1

    global root3
    root3 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root3.grid(row = 8 , column = 1 )

    global root4
    root4 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root4.grid(column=11,row=18)

    btn01 = Button(root3, text="Q",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("Q"))
    btn01.grid(column=3, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn02 = Button(root3, text="W",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("W"))
    btn02.grid(column=4, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn03 = Button(root3, text="E",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("E"))
    btn03.grid(column = 5, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn04 = Button(root3, text="R",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("R"))
    btn04.grid(column=6, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn05 = Button(root3, text="T",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("T"))
    btn05.grid(column=7, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn06 = Button(root3, text="Y",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("Y"))
    btn06.grid(column=8, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn07 = Button(root3, text="U",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("U"))
    btn07.grid(column=9, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn08 = Button(root3, text="I",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("I"))
    btn08.grid(column=10, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn09 = Button(root3, text="O",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("O"))
    btn09.grid(column=11, row=8,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn10 = Button(root3, text="P",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("P"))
    btn10.grid(column=12,row=8,padx=2, pady=2)

    btn11= Button(root3, text="A",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("A"))
    btn11.grid(column=4, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn12 = Button(root3, text="S",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("S"))
    btn12.grid(column=5, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn13 = Button(root3, text="D",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("D"))
    btn13.grid(column=6, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn14 = Button(root3, text="F",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("F"))
    btn14.grid(column=7, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn15= Button(root3, text="G",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("G"))
    btn15.grid(column=8, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn16 = Button(root3, text="H",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("H"))
    btn16.grid(column=9, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn17 = Button(root3, text="J",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("J"))
    btn17.grid(column=10, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn18 = Button(root3, text="K",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("K"))
    btn18.grid(column=11, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn19 = Button(root3, text="L",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("L"))
    btn19.grid(column=12, row=9,padx=2, pady=2)

    btn20 = Button(root3, text="Z",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("Z"))
    btn20.grid(column=5, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn21 = Button(root3, text="X",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("X"))
    btn21.grid(column=6, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn22 = Button(root3, text="C",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("C"))
    btn22.grid(column=7, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn23 = Button(root3, text="V",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("V"))
    btn23.grid(column=8, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn24 = Button(root3, text="B",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("B"))
    btn24.grid(column=9, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn25 = Button(root3, text="N",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("N"))
    btn25.grid(column=10, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)
    btn26 = Button(root3, text="M",bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",width=3,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda: clicked("M"))
    btn26.grid(column=11, row=10,padx=2, pady=2)

    btn30 = Button(root4, text="SUBMIT",bg="Cyan", fg="Black",width=8,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=lambda:submit)
    btn30.grid(column=11, row=18,pady=5)

    global label3
    if word == 'CLOCK':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT HAS A FACE AND TWO HANDS\n BUT NO  ARMS OR LEGS",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word =='BOTTLE':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT HAS A NECK BUT NO HEAD",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'TOWEL':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT GETS WETTER AS IT DRIES",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'ELEVEN':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: HOW MANY LETTERS ARE THERE IN ALPHABET?",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'AGE':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT GOES UP BUT NEVER DOWN",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'TABLE':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT HAS 4 LEGS BUT CAN'T WALK ",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'WINDOW':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: THIS INVENTION LETS YOU LOOK\n RIGHT THROUGH THE WALL",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'EGG':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT HAS TO BE BROKEN BEFORE YOU USE IT",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'SPIDER':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT BUILD ITS HOUSE WITH EARTHEN STRING\n AND ENSNARES ITS PREY WITH A BITTING STING",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'D':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: COMPLETE THE SEQUENCE\n  JFMAMJJASON_",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'NEEDLE':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT HAS ONE EYE BUT CANNOT SEE",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'RELATIONSHIP':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT IS A SHIP WHICH HAS TWO MATES,\n BUT NO CAPTAIN",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'ENVELOPE':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT BEGINS WITH 'E' AND ENDS WITH 'E'\n BUT ONLY HAS ONE LETTER",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'EDWIN':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: SECOND MAN TO STEP ON MOON",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word == 'DEATH':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: SOME TRY TO HIDE,\n SOME TRY TO CHEAT BUT TIME WILL SHOW,\n WE ALWAYS WILL MEET.\n TRY AS YO MIGHT TO  GUESS MY NAME ",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word =='SUN':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: NEVER RESTING, NEVER STILL, MOVING SILENTLY\n FROM HILL TO HILL,\n IT DOES NOT WALK, RUN OR TROT,\n ALL IS COOL WHERE IT IS NOT ",font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)

    window.mainloop()

def difficulty():
    global root1
    root1 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root1.grid(row=4,column=6)
    global label1
    label1=Label(text="SELECT A DIFFICULTY LEVEL",pady = 30,font = "Times 20")
    label1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    btn27 = Button(root1, text="EASY",bg="YELLOW", fg="Black",width=8,height=1,bd=10,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=EASY )
    btn27.grid(row=4 , column=1,pady=20)
    btn28 = Button(root1, text="MEDIUM",bg="Green", fg="Black",width=8,height=1,bd=10,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=MEDIUM)
    btn28.grid(row=8 , column=1,pady=20)
    btn29 = Button(root1, text="HARD",bg="RED", fg="Black",width=8,height=1,bd=10,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=HARD)
    btn29.grid(row=12 , column=1,pady=20)

def EASY():
    global chances
    chances=8
    global words
    words=random.choice(easy)
    root1.destroy()
    label1.destroy()
    global label2
    label2=Label(text="TOTAL CHANCES : 8",font="Times 18")
    label2.grid(row=14,column=0,pady=15)
    emptyblocks(words)


def MEDIUM():
    global chances
    chances=10
    global words
    words=random.choice(med)
    root1.destroy()
    label1.destroy()
    global label2
    label2=Label(text="TOTAL CHANCES : 10",font="Times 18")
    label2.grid(row=14,column=0,pady=15)
    emptyblocks(words)

def HARD():
    global chances
    chances=15
    global words
    words=random.choice(hard)
    root1.destroy()
    label1.destroy()
    global label2
    label2=Label(text="TOTAL CHANCES : 15",font="Times 18")
    label2.grid(row=14,column=0,pady=15)
    emptyblocks(words)

def clicked(alphabet):
    global chances
    global img
    global label4
    global label5
    global answer
    global ans
    ans=[]
    answer = []
    for i in range(n):
        c=ord(words[i])
        ans.insert(i,c)    
    j=0
    while j<n:
        if words[j] == alphabet:
            button[j]["text"] = alphabet
            d=ord(alphabet)
            answer.insert(j,d)
        j=j+1      
    else:
        chances=chances-1
        txt="CHANCES REMAINING: "+str(chances);
        label2.configure(text=txt)

    if chances<0:
        root2.destroy()
        root3.destroy()
        root4.destroy()
        label2.destroy()
        label3.destroy()
        load=Image.open('hangman1.png')
        render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img=Label(image=render)
        img.image=render
        img.grid(row=0,column=15)
        label4=Label(text="YOU LOOSE GET READY TO HANG",font="Times 18")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=15,pady=20)




def submit():
    ans.sort()
    answer.sort()
    if ans == answer:
        root2.destroy()
        root3.destroy()
        root4.destroy()
        label2.destroy()
        label3.destroy()
        load=Image.open('win.png')
        render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img=Label(image=render)
        img.image=render
        img.grid(row=0,column=15)
        label4=Label(text="CONGRATULATIONS YOU WIN",font="Times 18")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=15,pady=20)







window = Tk()
window.title("HANGMAN GAME")
window.geometry("3000x1000")
easy=['CLOCK','BOTTLE','TOWEL','ELEVEN','AGE','WINDOW','TABLE']
med=['EGG','SPIDER','D','NEEDLE']
hard=['RELATIONSHIP','ENVELOPE','EDWIN','DEATH','SUN']
difficulty()
```

The code first executes as it asks to which difficulty level is to selected.Then in next case it tells you to input letters to the the hidden word which has to be guessed in given chances. If chances is less then zero the game gets over but when I enter proper letters and try to submit the letters the submit function does not get executed.
Can anyone help me with this.
THANK YOU!!!

Comment: "Doesn't seem to work" _How_ is it not working? Tell us with an [edit] how this code is being invoked and how it is not working. Have you proven to yourself this code is ever run? You need to tell us what problem you are having before we can help you.

Comment: I am using a button which when clicked will directly go on to this code and perform the statements above

Comment: [EDIT] the question and gives us the details. Have you proven that this code is _ever_ reached? How? Maybe this button handler code is never invoked. Put simply: you need to spend some time learning how to debug your own code because SO is a _terrible_ debugger. See: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and see [ask].

Comment: I could have a posted and  explained all the code if u want but last time went I posted the thread was closed so I just posted the main region of which I have a doubt of ..

Comment: If it was closed then the community decided it didn't meet the basic requirements for this site. However, that has nothing to do with this question. Have you read [ask] and taken the [tour]? No one can answer this question for you without knowing what exact problem you are running into. It is unclear if this code is _ever_ run, and only _you_ are able to prove this. All you have to  do is put `print(...)` lines in this method and run it! Do those print lines ever get reached? Is the method ever reached? Is the test ever reached? What happens if you put in an else branch and print that?

Comment: @jdv i have uploaded the entire code can you tell me what is the reason the submit function is not executing?

Comment: SO is _not_ a debugging service! What have you done to debug this? Have you tried _anything_? Step 1: is this handler ever called? Don't do anything until you know this.

Comment: I did as per what you had directed me to the link I read it and decided to debug it but that submit button made me confused . As it has written on the website I sat and debugged the code and also i needed the same thing which is given in the code but that submit button is not executing

Comment: So, you have proven that the submit is not being reached? You _know_ this without any doubt? Good. Now you ask the question "why is my lambda command not being called". This is the actual question you are now trying to solve. You should research how to associate a TKinter lambda with a component. But the first thing you want to do is prove that the button is being defined with that lambda, and that the syntax you are using is correct.

Comment: It may be useful for you to simplify this to the smallest example so you understand it before moving on. See: https://pythonprogramming.net/passing-functions-parameters-tkinter-using-lambda/

Comment: I have got the error but I can't solve it @jdv  .The error is in this line which gives me an list so that both the i can check both the word and the guessed letter if it is correct or  not             :  if words[j] == alphabet:
            button[j]["text"] = alphabet
            d=ord(alphabet)
            answer.insert(j,d)    It is inside the clicked function the list gets only the last value entered. So what is the reason for this?

Comment: You should [edit] the question and make it clear what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure whether this will fix anything, i would have commented however I do not have the right amount of reputation.

You could try getting rid of the lambda function and could have just had the function name as there are no arguments needed.

```
btn30 = Button(root4, text="SUBMIT",bg="Cyan", fg="Black",width=8,height=1,font=('Helvetica','20'),command=submit)
btn30.grid(column=11, row=18,pady=5)
```

Not too sure if this will work but worth giving a shot.
Sorry if this doesn't work but I am unable to comment.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the lists `ans` and `answer`. One thing is that you create the empty list `answer` for each press of a key button in the function `clicked()`. This means thay you will only ever have the last letter clicked in `answer`.

Also, mutable datatypes behave differently when made global, eg. the lists `ans` and `answer`. You don't need them to be global in order to change their contents. The easiest way I find is to declare them in the global namespace and then just change them inside functions. No need to have them global inside functions.

I have also taken much of the code out to make it simpler to debug:

```
from tkinter import*
import random
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def emptyblocks(word):
    global n
    global root2
    root2 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root2.grid(row=5 , column=1)
    n = len(word)
    i = 0
    # Setting ans only once
    for i in range(n):
        c = ord(words[i])
        ans.insert(i,c)

    global button
    button = []
    for j in range(n):
        btni = Button(root2, text=" ", bg="White", fg="Black",
                      width=3, height=1, font=('Helvetica','20'))
        btni.grid(column=i+3, row=4, pady=40)
        button.append(btni)
        i=i+1

    global root3
    root3 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root3.grid(row = 8 , column = 1 )

    global root4
    root4 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root4.grid(column=11,row=18)

    for row, keys in enumerate(['QWERTYUIOP', 'ASDFGHJKL', 'ZXCVBNM']):
        for col, char in enumerate(keys):
            btn = Button(root3, text=char, bg="skyBlue", fg="Black",
                         width=3, height=1, font=('Helvetica','20'),
                         command=lambda c=char: clicked(c))
            btn.grid(column=col+3+row, row=8+row, padx=2, pady=2)

    btn30 = Button(root4, text="SUBMIT", bg="Cyan", fg="Black",
                   width=8, height=1, font=('Helvetica','20'),
                   command=submit)
    btn30.grid(column=11, row=18, pady=5)

    global label3
    if word == 'CLOCK':
        label3=Label(text="HINT: IT HAS A FACE AND TWO HANDS\n BUT NO  ARMS OR LEGS", font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    elif word =='BOTTLE':
        label3 = Label(text="HINT: IT HAS A NECK BUT NO HEAD", font="Times 18")
        label3.grid(row=2,column=0)
    window.mainloop()

def difficulty():
    global root1
    root1 = Frame(window, relief=RIDGE)
    root1.grid(row=4,column=6)
    global label1
    label1 = Label(text="SELECT A DIFFICULTY LEVEL",pady = 30,font = "Times 20")
    label1.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
    btn27 = Button(root1, text="EASY", bg="YELLOW", fg="Black",
                   width=8, height=1, bd=10, font=('Helvetica','20'),
                   command=EASY )
    btn27.grid(row=4 , column=1,pady=20)

def EASY():
    global chances
    chances = 8
    global words
    words = random.choice(easy)
    root1.destroy()
    label1.destroy()
    global label2
    label2 = Label(text="TOTAL CHANCES : 8", font="Times 18")
    label2.grid(row=14, column=0, pady=15)
    emptyblocks(words)

def clicked(alphabet):
    global chances
    global img
    global label4
    global label5
    # Do not reset ans for every clicked letter
    j = 0
    while j < n:
        if words[j] == alphabet:
            button[j]["text"] = alphabet
            d = ord(alphabet)
            answer.insert(j, d)
        j = j + 1      
    else:
        chances = chances - 1
        txt = "CHANCES REMAINING: " + str(chances);
        label2.configure(text=txt)

    if chances < 0:
        root2.destroy()
        root3.destroy()
        root4.destroy()
        label2.destroy()
        label3.destroy()
        load = Image.open('hangman1.png')
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.grid(row=0, column=15)
        label4 = Label(text="YOU LOOSE GET READY TO HANG", font="Times 18")
        label4.grid(row=10, column=15, pady=20)

def submit():
    # You already have the answer: words
    # Compute the guess from buttons
    guess = ''.join([b['text'] for b in button])

    if guess == words:
        root2.destroy()
        root3.destroy()
        root4.destroy()
        label2.destroy()
        label3.destroy()
        load=Image.open('win.png')
        render=ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img=Label(image=render)
        img.image=render
        img.grid(row=0,column=15)
        label4=Label(text="CONGRATULATIONS YOU WIN",font="Times 18")
        label4.grid(row=10,column=15,pady=20)

answer = []
ans = []

window = Tk()
easy=['CLOCK','BOTTLE']
difficulty()
```

There are still issues. Try for example to press a letter twice when the word contains that letter. It will appear twice in the `answer` and a match will not be made with `ans`.

**Updated example**

I colundn't quite see how you reasoned when checking the answer, but here is a suggestion of how you can do it:

You already have the string you want to find: `words`. Then read all text from the line of buttons (`button`) above the keyboard. Then compare the two. I have updated the code in my example accordingly.

Comment: How can i rectify the issue you mentioned in the last @figbeam

Comment: Updated my example